# The meaning/implication of the matrices generated by Singular Value Decomposition (SVD) for Latent Semantic Analysis (LSA)

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, data-mining, text-mining, lda

SVD is used in LSA to get the latent semantic information. I am confused about the interpretation about the SVD matrices.

We first build a document-term matrix. And then use SVD to decompose it into 3 matrices.

For example:

The doc-term matrix M1 is  M x N, where:

```
M = the number of documents
N = the number of terms
```

And M1 was decomposed into:

```
M1 = M2 * M3 * M4, where:

M2: M x k

M3: k x k

M4: k x N
```

I see the interpretation like below:

The k **column** of M2 stands for categories of similar **semantics**.
The k **row** of M4 stands for the **topics**.

My questions are:

1. Why is k interpreted like above? How do we know it is similar semantics and topics?
2. Why the similar semantics equal the topics?
3. Why k is interpreted differently between M2 and M4
4. How to interpret the M3?

I am really confused. It seems the interpretation is totally arbitrary. Is that what **latent** meant to be?

Comment: If `SVD` seems too arbitrary, try using `PCA` instead. They're effectively equivalent, but `PCA` is much easier to convince yourself of and can help explain a lot of the reasoning behind `SVD` interpretation. A full explanation of `SVD` should either be on math exchange, or constitute most of a linear algebra course.

Comment: I think the question was about why k apparently has a similar-sounding-yet-differently-named interpretation in the different matrices.  Does it really?

Comment: @HeatherStark yes, that should be one of my concerns, too. Thanks for pointing it out. I updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I warmly recommend reading the information retrieval chapter in the SNLP bible by Manning and Schutze.
In 5 pages it explains everything you want to know about LSI and SVD.

You will find paragraphs like this :

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation of this book. I didn't read it before. I will read it.